# Azure Pipelines best practices for multiple services and environments

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I was hoping to get some feedback on using Azure Pipelines and what the best practices are for my situation.

We have recently migrated from TFS 2017 and we are in the process of re-writing all our pipelines.  We were using builds and releases prior to the upgrade in the legacy build tasks.  We would like to setup more useful YAML pipelines.

Let me set the stage with what we currently have

- 10+ microservices

  - 10 individual builds that trigger from a folder in the repo for each one
  - 10 releases that get created on successful build
  - 3 environments per release (Dev, QA, UAT)

So in summary... a build of a single microservice triggers off of a commit to a folder in the branch.  The successful build then triggers a release to Dev.  Dev completes and a user go go start a QA build by clicking the release.

[image]

In the new Azure Pipeline world... what would be the best approach to doing this model.

1. We would like to have all the builds happen in a single pipeline (each stage would be a microservice?)
2. How do we trigger only on a commit to that folder?
3. What would the CD look like?  Should it be in the same pipeline and be a new stage?
4. How can we easily just add environments without having to just keep copy/pasting all the code for each environment?  Ideally i would like to just be able to add a variable and a new environment can be deployed to

I am open to any suggestions here.  I am ok if I am way off here, I am looking for the best practices and best approach to this.

TIA